# ASP.NET MVC, NHibernate sessions, and NHibernate events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, httpmodule

I'm using (Fluent) NHibernate in an ASP.NET MVC3 project. I'm using the standard approach of opening one NHibernate session per request by implementing a custom HttpModule. The session gets opened in BeginRequest and closed in EndRequest.

I'm hooking into the Pre/Post Insert/Update events to write a history log for my entities. The problem arises when I try to save the entity in these event handlers. It seems as though EndRequest has already been called before these event handlers, and hence the NHibernate session is already closed.

How can I delay the closing of the session so I can save the history entities? I've looked at some of the HttpModules at [rhino commons](http://ayende.com/wiki/HttpModules.ashx), but it seems overkill for my situation.

Comment: Use a dedicated Session to perform these tasks, maybe? We use these events for auditing purposes also, and we perform these operations in a separate Session.

Comment: Those events occur within the transaction. You *are* using transactions, right?

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon Yes, everything within the request is handled in a transaction. The problem is that the request is ending before the event handlers are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [this post](http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener) by Ayende. I believe you'll find your answer in the comments made by Revin Hart. Ayende and Revin talk about getting a child session to handle saving the change log entity.

```
ISession newSession = ev.Source.PersistenceContext.Session.GetSession();

foreach (ScheduleChangeLog changeLog in logs)
{
    changeLog.UpdatedBy = Username;
    newSession.Save(changeLog);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Long story short I did have to create a new session.